# cakephp find() question

Tags: cakephp

I want to convert following mysql statement into cakephp query syntax.Please help me. Here is my query.`SELECT * FROM post WHERE (user_id == $id OR awarded_to = $id ) AND id = $id`

Here is my cakephp query. is it wrong.

```
 $this->Post->find('all', 
            array('conditions' => array('OR' =>
                                        array('Post.user_id' => $id),
                                        array('Post.awarded_to' => $id)
                                        ),
                                        'AND' =>
                                        array('Post.id' => $id)
                ))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one's on the house, but next time [read the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions).

```
   $this->Post->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' =>  array(
                    array('Post.user_id' => $id),
                    array('Post.awarded_to' => $id)
                ),
                'Post.id' => $id
            )
        ));
```

The 2 `OR` arrays need to be inside an array themself, and there's no need for `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Post.id = $id below the OR condition without you give "and" it's automatic read as and condition...

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
         'conditions' => array(
             'OR' => array('Post.user_id' => $id),
              array('Post.awarded_to' => $id)
         ),
         'Post.id' => $id
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close with your query, just you need little modification like to remove 'AND' in conditions array after 'OR' as:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' =>  array(
                array('Post.user_id' => $id),
                array('Post.awarded_to' => $id)
            ),
            'Post.id' => $id
        )
    ));
```

Or

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Post.id' => $id
        )
    ));
```

The second option will be the best for you if you are passing tables primary key 'id' in AND conditions.